# Manipulation of Integrals to Find Relationship Between Them

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^5}=k$. 
Find the value of the integral $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^6}$ in terms of k. Simplify the final answer as much as possible.

I am not sure at all where to begin here.
I know that there must be some relationship between the first integral and the second integral but I can't find it. I at first differentiated the first integral but that got me nowhere. Then I tried to solve/simplify the first integral by using trigonometric substitution, but I don't think that was a useful step either.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

$$\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^5}}_{x=\tan{\theta}} = \int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta\, \cos^8{\theta}$$

Now consider

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^6} = \int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta\, \cos^{10}{\theta} = \int_0^{\pi/4} d(\sin{\theta})\, \cos^{9}{\theta}$$

Integrate by parts...

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta\, \cos^{10}{\theta} &= \left [\sin{\theta} \cos^9{\theta} \right ]_0^{\pi/4} + 9 \int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta\, \cos^8{\theta} \sin^2{\theta}\\ &= \frac1{32} + 9 \int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta\, \cos^8{\theta} - 9 \int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta\, \cos^{10}{\theta}\end{align}$$

We may now solve for the desired integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta\, \cos^{10}{\theta} = \frac1{320} + \frac{9}{10} \int_0^{\pi/4} d\theta\, \cos^8{\theta}$$

or

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^6} =  \frac1{320} + \frac{9}{10} \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^5}$$

Comment: Okay, thank-you! How would you go about doing this question if the second integral was 1/(1-x^2)^6 ?

Comment: @user130996: I wouldn't - the second integral diverges.

Comment: @user130996: you should check this page again to see some updates.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick: Write $${\int_0^1}dx\frac{1}{(1+x²)⁶}={\int_0^1}dx\frac{1+x²-x²)}{(1+x²)⁶}={\int_0^1}dx\frac{1}{(1+x²)⁵}-{\int_0^1}dx\frac{x²}{(1+x²)⁶}=k-{\int_0^1}dx\frac{x²}{(1+x²)⁶}$$ and note that $$\frac{x²}{(1+x²)⁶}=-\frac{x}{10}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(1+x²)⁵}$$ Then $$\int_0^1dx\frac{x²}{(1+x²)⁶}=-\frac{1}{10}\int_0^1dxx\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(1+x²)⁵}=
-\frac{1}{10}\frac{x}{(1+x²)⁵}|₀¹
+\frac{1}{10}\times\int_0^1dx\frac{1}{(1+x²)⁵}=\frac{k}{10}-\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{2⁵}$$ etc.